# Cygwin and Conda: activate, deactivate do not work properly

Tags: python, cygwin, conda

I'm using Cygwin and Conda package management on Windows 10, and using Cygwin is being really quirky and I can't seem to figure out what's going on.

Commands like `activate myEnv` do not work (as docs suggest) in Cygwin terminal, but `conda activate myEnv` would work. I also cannot install applications on an activated environment -- it says there's no environment in the environment folder. If I specifiy the environment name, things work fine. I can't deactivate environments.

Do I just need to do a complete uninstall or any piece of advice on my setup?

**Listing the environments:**

```
joshua@Josh-Laptop ~
$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3
MLenv                    C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\envs\MLenv
Web                      C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\envs\Web
ml                       C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\envs\ml
```

**Trying to activate the environment MLenv**

```
joshua@Josh-Laptop ~
$ activate MLenv
```

**Problem is base is still selected**

```
joshua@Josh-Laptop ~
$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3
MLenv                    C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\envs\MLenv
Web                      C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\envs\Web
ml                       C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\envs\ml
```

**Trying to activate again (works with conda specified)**

```
joshua@Josh-Laptop ~
$ conda activate MLenv
```

**But no asterisk next to environment?**

```
(MLenv)
joshua@Josh-Laptop ~
conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3
MLenv                    C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\envs\MLenv
Web                      C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\envs\Web
ml                       C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\envs\ml
```

**Trying to install a package, Environment not found??**

```
(MLenv)
joshua@Josh-Laptop ~
conda install scikit-learn

EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: 
C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\envs\MLenv
```

**Trying again, but specifying environment (recognizes location now).**

```
(MLenv)
joshua@Josh-Laptop ~
conda install scikit-learn -n MLenv
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\envs\MLenv

  added / updated specs:
    - scikit-learn


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    scikit-learn: 0.19.1-py36h53aea1b_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
```

**Last but not least, I can't deactivate my environments**

```
)(MLenv)
joshua@Josh-Laptop ~
source deactivate

)(MLenv)
joshua@Josh-Laptop ~
conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3
MLenv                    C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\envs\MLenv
Web                      C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\envs\Web
ml                       C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\envs\ml

)(MLenv)
joshua@Josh-Laptop ~
deactivate

)(MLenv)
joshua@Josh-Laptop ~
conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3
MLenv                    C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\envs\MLenv
Web                      C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\envs\Web
ml                       C:\Users\joshu\Anaconda3\envs\ml
```

**Here are my Paths (with MLenv activated)**

```
) (MLenv)
joshua@Josh-Laptop ~
echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n" | nl
     1  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/envs/MLenv
/Library/mingw-w64/biners/joshu/Anaconda3/envs/MLenv
/Library/usr/bine/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/envs/MLenv
/Library/bindrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/envs/MLenv
/Scripts/cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/envs/MLenv
/bin 6  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/envs/MLenv
     7  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/envs/MLenv
     8  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/envs/MLenv/Library/mingw-w64/bin
     9  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/envs/MLenv/Library/usr/bin
    10  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/envs/MLenv/Library/bin
    11  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/envs/MLenv/Scripts
    12  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/envs/MLenv/bin
    13  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3
    14  /usr/local/bin
    15  /usr/bin
    16  /cygdrive/c/Cygwin/bin
    17  /cygdrive/c/users/joshu
    18  /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client
    19  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client
    20  /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32
    21  /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS
    22  /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem
    23  /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
    24  /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL
    25  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL
    26  /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT
    27  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT
    28  /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit
    29  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin
    30  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon
    31  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/PuTTY
    32  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.8.19/bin
    33  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64
    34  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3
    35  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/Scripts
    36  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/Library/bin
    37  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/ffmpeg/bin
    38  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
    39  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin
    40  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin
    41  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin
    42  /cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin
    43  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/python.exe
    44  /usr/bin/python2.7.exe
    45  /usr/bin/aws
```

**Here are my paths (new window, no environments activate) **

```
joshua@Josh-Laptop ~
$ echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n" | nl
     1  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3
     2  /usr/local/bin
     3  /usr/bin
     4  /cygdrive/c/Cygwin/bin
     5  /cygdrive/c/users/joshu
     6  /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client
     7  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client
     8  /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32
     9  /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS
    10  /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem
    11  /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
    12  /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL
    13  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL
    14  /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT
    15  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT
    16  /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit
    17  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin
    18  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon
    19  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/PuTTY
    20  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.8.19/bin
    21  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64
    22  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3
    23  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/Scripts
    24  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/Library/bin
    25  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/ffmpeg/bin
    26  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
    27  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin
    28  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin
    29  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin
    30  /cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin
    31  /cygdrive/c/Users/joshu/Anaconda3/python
    32  /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/python
    33  /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/aws
```

Comment: I don't understand the use/purpose of `Cygwin` in any of that.

Comment: I use it as my CLI.. I could use `cmd` instead, but I like the functionality of having linux commands available to me (simple things like `ls` don't work for me in `cmd`)

Comment: Ok, but once you activate a specific environment, how many things do you expect to do in that specific environment? Personal opinion, but I activate an environment to do some limited tasks.

Comment: True, well I'd like to be able to deactivate the environment.